# RxJava2 with Room error handling - Database main thread exception

Tags: android, database, error-handling, reactive

I'm trying to retrieve items from a remote source, if this won't work (no internet) i'd like to retrieve cached items from a room database.
I have created a new single for when the error happens and I've specified on what thread it should subscribe and observe on. I still this exception though:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

This is the method for retrieving the items:

```
public LiveData<List<Article>> getNewsArticles() {
    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
            newsService.getNewsArticles()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

                    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable ->
                            Single.just(newsDao.findAllForNumber(AMOUNT_OF_ARTICLES_PER_PAGE))
                                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))

                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

                    .doOnSuccess(newsArticles -> Completable.fromAction(() ->
                            newsDao.insertAll(newsArticles))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                    .toFlowable());
}
```

LiveDataReactiveStreams converts it into a livedata object and handles the subscribtion, so my view only knows about livedata.

I just can't seem to make the onErrorResumeNext call work on a background thread.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**ANSWER**

I ended up solving tthe problem with the following code:

```
public LiveData<List<Article>> getNewsArticles() {
    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
            newsService.getNewsArticles()
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnSuccess(newsArticles -> newsDao.insertAll(newsArticles))
                    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> Single.fromCallable(() -> newsDao.findAllForNumber(AMOUNT_OF_ARTICLES_PER_PAGE)))
                    .toFlowable());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RxJava method [subscribeOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribeon.html) specify the Scheduler on which an Observable will operate. But method [observeOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html) specify the Scheduler on which an observer will observe this Observable.

**For simple:**

```
Single
.zip(observable1.getList(), observable2.getAnotherList()) // Simple zip for example
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // switch to main thread
.map(mapper.map(list1, list2)) // this command will execute on main thread
.observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // switch to io thread
.map(anotherMapper.map(complexList)) // this command will execute on io thread
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // switch to main thread
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // specify thread for zip command
```

ObserveOn works only downstream. All the methods following the observeOn have been moved to the IO thread. While the methods prior to the observeOn are still in the main thread.

In your example you somewhere try to call room dao command on main thread, and system does not allow to execute on main thread. You can set breakpoint on each command then in IDE look exactly thread name where command will be execute.

For more complex examples see this [article](https://proandroiddev.com/rx-java-subscribeon-and-observeon-a7d95041ce96).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I managed to solve the problem thanks to your help.